# Google App Script Get Multiple Index Positions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the index position of each repetition of a string.

The goal is to get each of those index positions and use the difference between each position to create a subtotal. The problem at hand is two fold. First, the distance between each string is not a standard length. Second, I seem to not be able to find out how to get multiple index positions of a particular string. I'm currently using the following code to cycle through different ranges to insert equations in to the sheet.

```
var Architecture = function(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var data = activeSheet.getRange(18, 2, 7, activeSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    var rowData = data[i];
    var checkData = data;
    var row = checkData[i];
    var colB = row[0]; 

    if(colB == 'Subtotal'){

      activeSheet.getRange(18 + i, 5, 1, data[0].length-4).setFormula('=iferror(sum(E' + (i+12) + ':E' + (i+17) + '))');
    }else{
      activeSheet.getRange(18 + i, 5).setFormula('=iferror(sum(F' + (i+18) + ':DU' + (i+18) + '))');
      activeSheet.getRange(18 + i, 6)
      .setFormula('=iferror(sum(filter(Invoices!$E:$E,Year(Invoices!$B:$B)=year(F$12),MONTH(Invoices!$B:$B)=Month(F$12),Invoices!$F:$F=$B' + (i+18) + ',Invoices!$A:$A=$C$2)))')
      .copyTo(activeSheet.getRange('F18:DU23'));
    }
  }
};

var DueDiligence = function(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var data = activeSheet.getRange(26, 2, 15, activeSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    var rowData = data[i];
    var checkData = data;
    var row = checkData[i];
    var colB = row[0]; 

    if(colB == 'Subtotal'){

 activeSheet.getRange(26 + i, 5, 1, data[0].length-4).setFormula('=iferror(sum(E' + (i+12) + ':E' + (i+25) + '))');
    }else{
      activeSheet.getRange(26 + i, 5).setFormula('=iferror(sum(F' + (i+26) + ':DU' + (i+26) + '))');
      activeSheet.getRange(26 + i, 6)
      .setFormula('=iferror(sum(filter(Invoices!$E:$E,Year(Invoices!$B:$B)=year(F$12),MONTH(Invoices!$B:$B)=Month(F$12),Invoices!$F:$F=$B' + (i+26) + ',Invoices!$A:$A=$C$2)))')
      .copyTo(activeSheet.getRange('F26:DU39'));
    }
  }
};
```

The goal would be to combine all these different functions into a single array that runs much quicker than the 18 seconds it currently takes to run.

EDIT

I've made some progress. Using the below function, I can get the index of each string, but it repeats that index position in the log for the number of rows that preceded it. For example, if the string is in index position two and then index position 10, the log shows 2,2,2,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 (only eight positions because 10-2=8).

```
var test = function(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var data = activeSheet.getRange(14, 2, activeSheet.getLastRow()-13,1).getValues();

var newData =  data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });

//Logger.log(newData);  

//Logger.log(data.indexOf("Subtotal", [i]));  

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

Logger.log(newData.indexOf("Subtotal", [i])); 
//    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Where is the string that you want to get the index position of in your data?

Comment: Okay so it’s column 2. I would let each unique string be the property of an object that holds an array of indexes. There is a lot of ways to do this. I would probably use reduce but that’s up to you.

Comment: I’m fairly new to this and haven’t used an object before. Can you explain a little bit how it works and how to set it up to hold an array of indexes? Or those indexes I pass from my looped indexOf function?

Comment: [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to retrieve the indexes of all elements of an array called `"Subtotal"`.

This can be done in a single line by combining [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var indexes = newData.map((element, i) => element === "Subtotal" ? i : "")
                     .filter(element => element !== "");
```

In this case, map returns an array with the matching indexes as well as empty strings (for unmatching indexes), and filter removes the empty string elements.

#### Edit:

If you want to retrieve an array with the differences between an index and the previous one, you can do this (the first index will be the same in this case):

```js
var differences = indexes.map((element, i) => i == 0 ? element : element - indexes[i-1]);
```

#### Reference:

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: How then would I subtract one index position from the previous and then use that to set a subtotal range?

Comment: So what I have is essentially a budget sheet with subtotals for each section of spend. Unfortunately, the spend sections are not all uniform and so I can't just set an equation that sum's a set number of rows. What I need to do is find the relative distance between one subtotal row and the next. Then use that count to determine how many rows my new subtotal formula should be adding. I.e, if I have subtotal in row 15 and subtotal again in row 25 and again in row 27, how do I determine the difference between them.

Comment: @Squid1622 I edited my answer based on your comment. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
function getRowNumbersOfSameStrings() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let u={};
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(!u.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      u[r[0]]=[];
      u[r[0]].push(i+2);//row numbers
    }else{
      u[r[0]].push(i+2);//row numbers
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(u)), "Results");
}
```

Here's my sample data:

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8
7,2,4,0,1,1,10,4
9,3,2,5,2,6,7,6
9,2,10,10,9,7,2,11
10,7,2,10,2,6,2,0
0,2,4,0,6,3,10,0
2,7,6,7,0,3,5,8
6,9,6,11,3,5,5,8
1,4,5,5,10,0,3,11
4,3,3,3,1,9,3,2
9,4,0,9,2,8,11,2
5,8,7,0,3,6,5,4
5,3,5,3,2,3,8,3
```

Results:

```
{"0":[6],"1":[9],"2":[7],"4":[10],"5":[12,13],"6":[8],"7":[2],"9":[3,4,11],"10":[5]}
```

Comment: So I have a couple of questions and I hope you will oblige because I'm only partly comprehending what's happening here. What does u={} do? I'm unsure of what the curly brackets do in that instance. When declaring "if(!u.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) is that saying "If the variable u does not have its own property"?

Comment: let u={}; creates an object.  `if(!u.hasOwnProperty(r[0]))` asking the question does the object u have a property named r[0]. If it doesn't then I create one and if it does then push another index onto the array.